# Ruby Rails 3.2 Locale with folder_name path in URL

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a trio of Ruby/Rails applets running under the following setup:

```
services.mydomain.com/applet1
services.mydomain.com/applet2
services.mydomain.com/applet3
```

These are served via Phusion Passenger, and App1 and App2 work exactly as expected.

The problem is with App3 which uses I18n Locales embedded in the URL:

```
services.mydomain.com/applet3/en/
services.mydomain.com/applet3/fr/
services.mydomain.com/applet3/es/
```

The problem seems to be that the link_to URLs don't seem to include the "applet3".  So instead of:

```
services.mydomain.com/applet3/en/signin
```

I get:

```
services.mydomain.com/en/signin
```

... which is unrouteable.

My routes.rb looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

    match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
    match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
    match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

    match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
    match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
    root to: "static_pages#home"
  end # scope locale

end # Rails.application.routes.draw do
```

... and in app/controllers/application_controller.rb I have:

```
  before_filter :set_locale_from_params

  def url_options
    { only_path: true, locale: I18n.locale }
  end

  protected
    def set_locale_from_params
      if params[:locale]
        if I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale].to_sym)
          I18n.locale = params[:locale]
        else
          flash.now[:notice] = 'Translation not available'
          logger.error flash.now[:notice]
        end
      end
    end
```

... and in config/environments/production.rb I have:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'http://services.mydomain.com/applet3/'
```

EDIT1: add example link_to statement

```
<%= link_to(t(".#{language}"), root_path(locale: language)) %>
```

/EDIT1

If I move App3 to a more "normal" arrangement where there is no "folder_name" in the URL path, everything works fine.  So it's something simple I'm missing with how to set up the scope or the URL Options.

Thanks in advance for any help & suggestions!

Comment: No.  The issue is that the url_for helper is creating links that don't seem to have the right sub-folder in the path.  Thus, the matching route doesn't exist.  So, changing the route side won't fix the problem.

Comment: Incidentally, manually entering the corrected URLs -does- work, so routing itself works as expected.  The issue is entirely in URL creation to use the sub-folder/ sub-URI

Comment: Can you write your `link_to`?

Comment: @ProGNOMmers - Done; example above. It's pretty vanilla stuff.

Answer (score 0):

what about use constraints into your route to define your sub module route ?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 constraints(:host) do
  scope :path => ":locale" , locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    resources :users
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

    match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
    match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
    match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

    match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
    match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
    root to: "static_pages#home"
  end # scope locale
 end # constraints 

end # Rails.application.routes.draw do
```

Comment: Does not fix the issue.  URLs created continue to not have the 'applet3/' included, resulting in unroutable URLs.  As indicated in the comments, the issue seems to be URL creation, not routing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using root_path and expecting applet3 to be added, on doing rake routes did you check what was the path for root ?

You might have to explicitly set the root path in your routes file to enable routes_path work properly.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean about explicitly setting the root path?

Comment: root :to => redirect('/applet3')
probably ull have to match all the routes to it too.
match '/applet3', --- all the routes